# Wrong type of property of features in feature collection for random forest classification

Tags: google-earth-engine, point, random

i want to make classification of crop types by using random forest classifier, i created random points inside boundaries of crop fields, set properties as type of crops to them and wanted to make classification, however it doesnt classifies as the type of property is not float as expected.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/bc84e71a48869f0808df9dca86bfe627

```
    winter_barley = ee.FeatureCollection("users/mustakhimova_galiya1/ozim_yachmen"),
    study_area = ee.FeatureCollection("users/mustakhimova_galiya1/study_are");
var crops = winter_barley.merge(corn)



// Function to mask

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60')
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0))
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B.*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])
}


// Filter collection

var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterDate('2021-03-01', '2021-08-31')
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
    .filterBounds(crops)
    .map(maskS2clouds)
    .median()
   

print(sentinel2)

// Function ndvi
 var ndvi = sentinel2.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename(['NDVI']);


// Final image with ndvi
var final_image = sentinel2.addBands(ndvi)

print(final_image)



//Bands for prediciton
var bands = ['B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B9','B10','B11','B12','NDVI']


// clip image with study area

var final_image_clip = final_image.clip(study_area).select(bands)



// create feature_collection of points of crops 


//winter_barley
var winter_barley_rp = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(winter_barley, 50).set('type','1.0')
print(winter_barley_rp)

var winter_barley_rp1 = winter_barley_rp.map(function(feature) {
  var add_id = feature.set('type','1.0')
  return add_id
})

print(winter_barley_rp1,'winter_barley_rp')

Map.addLayer(winter_barley_rp)


//corn_rp
var corn_rp = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(corn, 50).set('type','3.0')

var corn_rp1 = corn_rp.map(function(feature) {
  var add_id = feature.set('type','3.0')
  return add_id
})


// merge samples


var merged_gcp = winter_barley_rp1.merge(corn_rp1)


var points = final_image_clip.select(bands).sampleRegions({
    collection: merged_gcp, 
    properties: ['type'],
    scale: 10
      }).randomColumn()

print(points,'points')

var training = points.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random',0.6));
var validation = points.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random',0.6));



var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(50).train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'type',
  inputProperties: final_image_clip.bandNames()
});


var classified = final_image_clip.classify(classifier)


Map.addLayer(classified)

print(training)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you changed the types to numbers, you still made them strings.
This: `"1.0"` is not the same as `1.0`.  Remove the quotes from around the numbers on lines 60 and 73.

Also, setting the type on the whole collection doesn't do anything.  (end of lines 56 and 70).

Comment: Thank you very much!